# How to hide first image when click on another images using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, show-hide

jQuery code - I used images as tab when click on image it will give us another images on that image with display content but when click on another images first image is not going to hide.

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/p44mhn5j/28/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('ul.tabs li').click(function(){

        var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');

        $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
        $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');

        $(this).addClass('current');
        $("#"+tab_id).addClass('current');
    });
});

$(function() {

    $("#images").find('img').bind("click", function() {
        var src = $(this).attr("src");

        // Check the beginning of the src attribute  
        var state = (src.indexOf("mainslice") === 0) ? 'mainslice' : 'clr';

        // Modify the src attribute based upon the state var we just set
        (state === 'mainslice') ? src = src.replace('mainslice', 'slice') : src = src.replace('slice', 'mainslice');
        // Apply the new src attribute value  
        $(this).attr("src", src);

        $("#images").hide();
        $("#images").show();

        // This is just for demo visibility
        // $('body').append('<p>' + $(this).attr('src') + '</p>');
    });
});
```

This is CSS code :

```
home {
  background: url(mainslice1.png);
  width: 98px;
  height: 45px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.3;
  background: #bdc3c7;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  width: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.tabs {
  background: url(slice3.png);
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
  background: #2c3e50;
  border-bottom: 5px #e67e22 solid;
}

.tabs li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  /*padding: 10px 20px 5px 20px;
    cursor: pointer;

    font-size:1.2em;
    line-height:2em;*/

  color: #FFF;
}

.tabs li:hover {
  background: #d35400;
}

.tabs li.current {
  background: #e67e22;
  color: #FFF;
}

.tab-content {
  background: url(mainslice1.png);
  display: none;
  /*background: #ededed;*/

  padding: 15px;
  line-height: 1.4;
}

.tab-content.current {
  background: url(mainslice1.png);
  display: inherit;
}
```

Comment: create a fiddle for this

Answer (score 1):

You need to first hide all the images inside "#images" and then show the current clicked image.

```
$("img").hide();     //to hide all images
$(this).show();      // to show currently clicked image
```

Comment: No it is not working.it is going to hide all the imags.

Comment: Could you make a demo on jsfiddle.net so we can see what you mean?

Comment: Please check that link and tell me what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('img').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('preserved'); // Add class to mark our image.
    $('img').hide(); // Hide all images.
    $('.preserved').show(); // Show the marked image.
});
```

You may want to narrow down the `img` selector to include only images in the container you need.

Comment: When I will click on another image then it will give new image and first image will get as it is..

Comment: Check this updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/p44mhn5j/29/ and try clicking on any blue images.

Comment: hello Justas no it is not working.. It will have to work like tab or menu.